# Do I, Ghanaian, need a transit visa at Istanbul airport on Turkish Airlines for connecting to Singapore?

Tags: layovers, turkey, transit-visas, ghanaian-citizens

I am a Ghanaian travelling on Turkish Airlines from Nigeria to Singapore. There is a long layover from 6am to 1am before boarding my next flight.

Do I need to acquire a transit visa before I can  board Turkish Airlines?

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you are planning to stay on the airport or to step out of the airport to vist Istanbul!!

But as a citizen of Ghana and want to visit Istanbul with ordinary or official passport, you are required to have visa to enter Turkey.